# Update existing nodes via cron

Tags: nodes

I need to update my nodes created from my own module. The data is extract from my database external.

Now, I want to update this nodes via hook_cron.. My question is: What is the function that update nodes? Or the steps for do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your looking for [node_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/6). You can [node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/6) your node and make changes to the object and then use node_save to save the changes.